# .net maui shell tabbar - how do i make it invisible?

Tags: maui

It looks like you can set a tabbar inside of a shell if the tabs are defined within the shell.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs

According to the documentation, I can set the visibility of the tabbar by referencing the shell.CurrentItem which is a static object.  Ok.  Danged if I can figure out how to reference the TabBarVisibility property or find anything that looks like that property.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Wally

Answer (score 3):

No, it has nothing to do with `Shell.Current.CurrentItem`.
That is part of the previous section in doc, not part of hiding tabbar.

Look at the next code snippet. The first one in section [TabBar and Tab Visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs#tabbar-and-tab-visibility):

```xml
...
    <ShellContent Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false" ...
```

`Shell.TabBarIsVisible` is an [Attached Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/attached-properties).

---

To set programmatically in c# code behind:
`Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(someView, false);`
where `someView` is the `x:Name` of a "shell content" (a page shown when corresponding tab is selected) that when it is showing, tabbar should be hidden.

Comment: ok, thanks.  That makes sense.  I had seen the SetTabBarIsVisible method, but didn't quite grok what was going on.  It takes a while and I am admittedly dense on learning new things.